# Cache function not storing results

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to reduce the amount of queries to my DB by using the react cache function however every time I re-navigate to the page I can see prisma logging a query.

It actually seems to be a bit hit and miss. When I first start the server and go to the page, I see the query being sent, I then go to another page via a  then back to the query page and the query runs again. Typically then I can go back and forward a few times without the query running but then after 5 or so times the query runs everytime I go to the page. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this.

getProjectById.ts

```
import prisma from "@/libs/prismadb";
import { cache } from "react";

export const revalidate = 3600; // revalidate the data at most every hour

// Get single project by UserId and ProjectId
export default cache(async (userId: string, projectId: string) => {
  const project = await prisma.project.findUnique({
    where: {
      ...
    }
  return project;
});
```

This is then called from my layout.tsx and various page.tsx within that layout. It's a slight over simplification of the structure but is hopefully enough to get the problem across.

layout.tsx

```
async function Layout({
  children,
  params,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { project: string };
}) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  const projectById = await getProjectById(session?.user.id!, params.project);
  if (projectById === null) {
    return notFound();
  }
```

page.tsx

```
sync function page({ params }: { params: { project: string } }) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  const projectById = await getProjectById(session?.user.id!, params.project);
  if (projectById === null) {
    return notFound();
  }
```